# How can I place 4 videos in a Side Scroll view I did in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, avplayer, xcode-storyboard

I am tying to place 4 videos, side by side in a scroll view I have created in a storyboard. The side scroll works as expected, and I also have a basic video player going, so I have the video working, but its not constrained to the scroll view. I am assuming I need to tell the video to be in the scroll view and to constrain to the height of the scroll view, but haven't been able to find any tutorials that talk about that specifically. I am also assuming I would need to set some coordinates for the other videos to place them side by side? or is it similar to html/css where I can set some padding or space between? See attached for how I set up the scroll view, and below is my video code.

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "final-S3-r1", ofType: "mp4")!))
        
        let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        layer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        player.volume = 0
        player.play()
    }

}
```

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkFJ3.png)

Comment: A stack view inside a scroll view with paging enable should work

Comment: Not related to your question but try learning View Code and forget about storyboards.

Comment: you can use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) for it